# 3D Scatter Plots: Changing point size for each series

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a `ListPointPlot3D` containing four series of data. I would like to be able to define the size, shape and colour of these series individually. Changing the size and colour is crucial, the shape not so much.

The Mathematica documentation is unhelpful for the 3D case, but for 2D plots I managed to get things to work perfectly.

Can anyone advise how best to do this in 3D?,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make up some data:

```
Table[data[k] = 
      Table[3 k + Sin[j^2 + i], {i, -Pi, Pi, 0.2}, {j, -2, 2, 0.2}], {k, 4}];
```

Apply different styles via `PlotStyle` and `Directive` to different data sets:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]},
  PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Opacity[.5], Red, PointSize[.005]],
   Directive[Opacity[.5], Blue, PointSize[.01]],
   Directive[Opacity[.5], Green, PointSize[.015]],
   Directive[Opacity[.5], Black, PointSize[.02]]
   }, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]